# Random crashes on my WIndows server machine

Tags: windows, ssd, server-crashes

This week I am getting curious random crashes on one of my Windows machines. Crash always ends with BSOD but with random error codes in random system drivers. No record in Event log.

So first guess is memory, but I realized that there is only one SSD disk inside. I do not trust in any SMART data from disks, but this time maybe this is the case when I should. What do you think? Self-test of the disk with Parted magic was ok. I cannot afford to do the write test.

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   120   120   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0/0
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       4581h+05m+42.650s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       290
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       11
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   128   129   000    Old_age   Always       -       128 (0 127 0 129 0)
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate  0x001c   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
204 Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate   0x001c   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
230 Life_Curve_Status       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1319
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       944
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       944
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       1317


Model Family:     SandForce Driven SSDs
Device Model:     Corsair Force 3 SSD
```

Comment: No record in the System log? Really? Normally, a BSOD will generate a BugCheck (EventID 7) event. Even if you think the BSOD errors are random, you should provide examples including the hexadecimal error codes, drivers named, etc. We may be able to see a pattern that is not immediately apparent to you. You indicated your first guess was memory, but you did not mention having run `memtest86`. Please do that and include the results.

Comment: You sure do reboot a lot, even by Windows standards. That's a bit of a concern. Beyond that, I see no evidence of your SSD causing any issues.

Comment: Ok, so I'm running memtest86 a I will try to exclude PSU/Mem/motherboard fault. Miles: that's why I looked at the disk, it seems that it cannot write anything after BSOD..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it folks. There is a huge bug in these SSDs regarding the sleep mode. If disk enters the sleep mode, there might be sometimes problem to wake it up, as it ignores COM_WAK statement. I don't know why it started to do it now, maybe it was caused by Windows update.

However, I updated every firmware of the system and after updating the disks firmware to 5.3, crashes are away.

Comment: Nope. Contact vendor, get firmware update. Depending on model etc. - well - the SSD firmware is totally - and i mean totally - crappy. OCZ was famous for that. Fixed now. Check your firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Did it at least create a memory dump? If not, check to see if your system is configured to create memory dumps, wait for it to happen again, and use Windbg to review the memory.dmp file.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   128   129   000    Old_age   Always       -       128 (0 127 0 129 0)
```

Um, assuming this is actually accurate, the problem is that your computer's getting hot enough to boil water.  So, what you need to do is invest in a proper kettle for your water-boiling needs, and keep your computer a lot cooler, instead of using it to generate steam.

Comment: Someone just told me that SSDs often don't have temperature probes, and give invalid data for this value, so this might lead you down the wrong path.